# Jump from Text Editor to Class View in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I would really love Visual Studio (2017) to open a specific class in Class View, given the selection in the Text Editor.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. After a lot of hassle, I found it here:
Tools, Customize. Select the Commands tab. Select the Toolbar radio button. Choose Standard from the dropdown list. Click on the Add Command. Scroll down to and select the View item. Scroll down to and click on Synchronize Class View. Works like a charm!

Comment: You're answer is correct (vote up) but I expect a way to add this menu item to class view toolbar that is wisely.

Answer (score 1):

A keyboard short cut is also possible.

`Tools==>Options`    Then Select  `[Keyboard]`

Map a key combo you never use to sync the view.

[image]